# BeautifulSoup search on beautifulsoup result?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Scraping a hotel website to retrieve titles and prices.
"hotelInfo" is the `div` that holds the interesting content.

It makes sense to me that I would want to only perform my operations on this `div`. My code is as follows -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("http://$hotelurlhere.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
hotelInfo = soup.select('div.hotel-wrap')
hotelTitle = soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'p-name'})

hotelNameList = []
hotelPriceList = []

for hotel in hotelInfo:
  for title in hotelTitle:
    hotelNameList.append(title.text)
```

It makes more sense to say that hotelTitle should be a Beautifulsoup search on hotelInfo above. However when I try this

```
hotelTitle = hotelInfo.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'p-name'})
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    hotelTitle = hotelInfo.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'p-name'})
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

An error was returned which was related to the list element not having an attribute of "find_all". I understand that this is because hotelInfo is a list element that was returned. I've searched for information on the correct way to check for the `h3` info within this list but I am not having any success.

What is the best way to do this? 
Shouldn't I be able to set hoteTitle to hotelInfo.find_all rather than just soup.find_all?

Comment: Your question is unclear . Please show sample HTML document with the expected output.

Comment: Updated with error message and clarification. Don't have sample data that I can share here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message clearly suggests, there is no `find_all()` method which you can invoke in a `list` object. In this case, you should call `find_all()` on individual member of the `list` instead, assuming that you need some information from the `div.hotel-wrap` as well as the corresponding `h3` :

```
for hotel in hotelInfo:
    hotelTitle = hotel.find_all('h3', attrs={'class': 'p-name'})
```

If you only need the `h3` elements, you can combine the two selectors to get them directly without having to find `hotelInfo` first :

```
hotelTitle = soup.select('div.hotel-wrap h3.p-name')
```

Answer (score -1):

For hotelinfo ,hoteltitle in zip (hotelinfos,hoteltitles):
       Data={
                   'hotelinfo':hotelinfo.get_text(),
}
      Print(data)

Like that